# Why Eclipse Paho Android MQTT Client Returns Subscribtion Failed?

Tags: android, mqtt, iot, adafruit

I can not subscribe to MQTT topic from my android application. 
When i call `SubscribeToTopic` function, I get the following Error

> "subscription to UserName/feeds/Topic failed: not available"

Here is the code to subscribe

```
    private void SubscribeToTopic(String TopicName, int Qos) {
    try {
        if (client.isConnected()) {
            client.subscribe(TopicName, Qos, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.d("Subscribtion", "Succeed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.d("Subscribtion", "Failed", exception);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (MqttException exception)
    {
        Log.d("Subscribtion","Failed",exception);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm using Eclipse Paho as my MQTT Client and Adafruit IO as Broker. TopicName is something like `UserName/feeds/Topic` and Qos is `0`

Comment: make sure you've already connected to Broker

Comment: @BryanYuan , I check the connection in 3rd line and then try to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours finally found solution. There was no problem with code, I only changed the topic to public mode in Adafruit IO dashboard and it worked. The only thing i can not understand is why it is possible to subscribe to private topic from Arduino library but it fails in android.